# How hard is it to tell the quality of a thermal paste?

Tags: laptop, cpu, cooling

I've taken my laptop apart and separated the cooling mechanism and cleaned off the cpu. I used naphtha and alcohol(50%). I've read many articles that I should have 99% Alcohol... not to use petroleum based cleaners... naphtha ehh... anyway, I ended up buying arctic 5 and it turns out my friend had some thermal paste. It was in a big white "toothpaste-like" container. I used that in the meantime(currently). Now that the arctic 5 has arrived, I'm wondering what's the point of taking this laptop apart again to re-clean the cpu and use the artic 5 thermal paste.

I think I did a good job of applying it as the computer hasn't had any problems, in fact it seems to be running better than before. Running cooler. I did this because I had separated the fan/cooling from the cpu when taking it apart in the past thus the thermal paste/bond was no longer "good".

Anyway, am I just having a moment of OCD...?

Comment: If it cools down your laptop (as what a good thermal paste should help to do) and does the job properly - then it is good. If you really want to be OCD, take measurement, log them, using the old paste and the new paste, and compare them. But really.. if the laptop is satisfactorily cool, there is no point (unless you like to open up the laptop as a practice)... - note: this is a personal opinion.

Comment: Right right, I don't know why I obsess over dumb things some times. Thanks.

Comment: agrees, if you have to use a backup paste, it will at least work for 6mo to 2 years, then you probably have to clean the laptop sometime anyways, do it then.

Comment: I've got a brand new tube of 'super, best you could ask for' paste sitting unopened in a drawer... so far I've resisted the temptation to take something apart unnecessarily just to try it out... but it won't be long...

Comment: There are several questions on SU about using substances like toothpaste.  IIRC, one of those has an answer that includes some data on cooling effectiveness of household products vs. several thermal paste products.  The answer to your question would be in there.   This is a common question and Google should have links to numerous product comparison tests.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you do some serious overclocking thermal paste does not matter that much, provided it is present and applied correctly. If the paste was of "not so good" quality it may dry out faster and then you can replace it.

Changing the paste in a laptop is a bit risky, because mobile processors usually do not have covers, so it is easy to damage the die.
No reason to change only because of the brand name, do it if you're having issues.

Comment: What do you mean about the "mobile processors do not have covers"? As in they aren't placed in those hinged-containers that keeps the processor in place by spring like in desktops? Yeah I was somewhat concerned when the naphtha appeared to be rubbing the plastic surrounding the raised shiny thing that I applied the paste on.  I mean so far so good. Computer's at 42C at the moment. It's a 6-7 year old computer.